# My command-line program does not find its config directory on CMD shell, but it does on PowerShell

Tags: windows, shell, powershell, path

I am using in my script a command-line program that does **not find its config directory on CMD shell, but it does on PowerShell**.

Even when this question seems to correspond to the behavior of some specific program (a command line hash analyzer tool named `OCLHashCat`), I think this is mostly a matter of Windows shells behavior and/or variables involved. Let me explain it.

This is the contents of the command line program's **directory** (`OCLHashCat`):

```
d:\Programas\HashCat\OCLHashCat>dir
 El volumen de la unidad D es Datos
 El número de serie del volumen es: 57E9-ACA0

 Directorio de d:\Programas\HashCat\OCLHashCat

07/10/2014  09:28 am    <DIR>          .
07/10/2014  09:28 am    <DIR>          ..
06/10/2014  11:56 pm    <DIR>          charsets
06/10/2014  11:56 pm    <DIR>          docs
06/10/2014  11:57 pm                 4 eula.accepted
02/10/2014  12:11 pm         1.210.228 example.dict
02/10/2014  12:11 pm           220.796 example0.hash
02/10/2014  12:11 pm                36 example400.hash
02/10/2014  12:11 pm                36 example500.hash
06/10/2014  11:56 pm    <DIR>          extra
02/10/2014  12:11 pm        33.685.504 hashcat.hcstat
06/10/2014  11:56 pm    <DIR>          kernels
06/10/2014  11:56 pm    <DIR>          masks
02/10/2014  12:11 pm                72 oclExample0.cmd
02/10/2014  12:11 pm                66 oclExample0.sh
02/10/2014  12:11 pm                68 oclExample400.cmd
02/10/2014  12:11 pm                61 oclExample400.sh
02/10/2014  12:11 pm                61 oclExample500.cmd
02/10/2014  12:11 pm                55 oclExample500.sh
15/11/2014  11:46 pm               128 oclHashcat.dictstat
07/10/2014  02:52 am            11.448 oclHashcat.log
07/10/2014  02:52 am    <DIR>          oclHashcat.outfiles
07/10/2014  02:03 am                 0 oclHashcat.pot
07/10/2014  09:28 am               400 oclHashcat.restore
02/10/2014  12:11 pm           388.744 oclHashcat32.bin
02/10/2014  12:11 pm           419.840 oclHashcat32.exe
02/10/2014  12:11 pm           383.136 oclHashcat64.bin
02/10/2014  12:11 pm           432.128 oclHashcat64.exe
06/10/2014  11:56 pm    <DIR>          rules
```

As you can see, the directory `kernels` is right there.
And the home dir of `OCLHashCat` is in my path:

```
C:\>oclhashcat64
oclHashcat v1.31 starting...

Usage: oclhashcat64 [options]... hash|hashfile|hccapfile [dictionary|mask|direct
ory]...

Try --help for more help.
```

But if I try to run, it **can not find** some of its own files/directories:

```
C:\Temporal>oclhashcat64 Test.hccap -m 2500 -a 3 ?d?d?d?d?d?d?d?d
oclHashcat v1.31 starting...

Device #1: Bonaire, 1024MB, 1050Mhz, 12MCU
Device #2: Tahiti, 3072MB, 900Mhz, 28MCU

Hashes: 1 hashes; 1 unique digests, 1 unique salts
Bitmaps: 8 bits, 256 entries, 0x000000ff mask, 1024 bytes
Applicable Optimizers:
* Zero-Byte
* Single-Hash
* Single-Salt
* Brute-Force
Watchdog: Temperature abort trigger set to 90c
Watchdog: Temperature retain trigger set to 80c
Device #1: Kernel ./kernels/4098/m02500.Bonaire_1573.4_1573.4 (VM).kernel not fo
und in cache! Building may take a while...

ERROR: ./kernels/4098/m02500.VLIW1.llvmir: No such file or directory
```

Note the final error: it can not find a file, but I have checked that **such file exists**:

```
C:\Temporal>dir d:\Programas\HashCat\OCLHashCat\kernels\4098\m02500.VLIW1.llvmir

 El volumen de la unidad D es Datos
 El número de serie del volumen es: 57E9-ACA0

 Directorio de d:\Programas\HashCat\OCLHashCat\kernels\4098

02/10/2014  12:11 pm           326.912 m02500.VLIW1.llvmir
               1 archivos        326.912 bytes
```

And, if I CHDir into the program's directory:

```
d:\Programas\HashCat\OCLHashCat>oclhashcat64 -m 2500 "c:\Temporal\Test.hccap" -a
 3 ?d?d?d?d?d?d?d?d
oclHashcat v1.31 starting...

Device #1: Bonaire, 1024MB, 1050Mhz, 12MCU
Device #2: Tahiti, 3072MB, 900Mhz, 28MCU

Hashes: 1 hashes; 1 unique digests, 1 unique salts
Bitmaps: 8 bits, 256 entries, 0x000000ff mask, 1024 bytes
Applicable Optimizers:
* Zero-Byte
* Single-Hash
* Single-Salt
* Brute-Force
Watchdog: Temperature abort trigger set to 90c
Watchdog: Temperature retain trigger set to 80c
Device #1: Kernel ./kernels/4098/m02500.Bonaire_1573.4_1573.4 (VM).kernel (25932
0 bytes)
Device #1: Kernel ./kernels/4098/markov_le_v1.Bonaire_1573.4_1573.4 (VM).kernel
(92404 bytes)
Device #1: Kernel ./kernels/4098/bzero.Bonaire_1573.4_1573.4 (VM).kernel (30496
bytes)
Device #2: Kernel ./kernels/4098/m02500.Tahiti_1573.4_1573.4 (VM).kernel (259428
 bytes)
Device #2: Kernel ./kernels/4098/markov_le_v1.Tahiti_1573.4_1573.4 (VM).kernel (
92388 bytes)
Device #2: Kernel ./kernels/4098/bzero.Tahiti_1573.4_1573.4 (VM).kernel (30492 b
ytes)

[s]tatus [p]ause [r]esume [b]ypass [q]uit =>
```

That is: everything works like a charm.

In **Powershell everything works perfect** wherever I call the program from. Example:

```
PS C:\Temporal> oclHashcat64.exe Test.hccap -m 2500 -a 3 ?d?d?d?d?d?d?d?d
oclHashcat v1.31 starting...

Device #1: Bonaire, 1024MB, 1050Mhz, 12MCU
Device #2: Tahiti, 3072MB, 900Mhz, 28MCU

Hashes: 1 hashes; 1 unique digests, 1 unique salts
Bitmaps: 8 bits, 256 entries, 0x000000ff mask, 1024 bytes
Applicable Optimizers:
* Zero-Byte
* Single-Hash
* Single-Salt
* Brute-Force
Watchdog: Temperature abort trigger set to 90c
Watchdog: Temperature retain trigger set to 80c
Device #1: Kernel d:\Programas\HashCat\OCLHashCat/kernels/4098/m02500.Bonaire_1573.4_1573.4 (VM).kernel (259320 bytes)
Device #1: Kernel d:\Programas\HashCat\OCLHashCat/kernels/4098/markov_le_v1.Bonaire_1573.4_1573.4 (VM).kernel (92404 bytes)
Device #1: Kernel d:\Programas\HashCat\OCLHashCat/kernels/4098/bzero.Bonaire_1573.4_1573.4 (VM).kernel (30496 bytes)
Device #2: Kernel d:\Programas\HashCat\OCLHashCat/kernels/4098/m02500.Tahiti_1573.4_1573.4 (VM).kernel (259428 bytes)
Device #2: Kernel d:\Programas\HashCat\OCLHashCat/kernels/4098/markov_le_v1.Tahiti_1573.4_1573.4 (VM).kernel (92388 bytes)
Device #2: Kernel d:\Programas\HashCat\OCLHashCat/kernels/4098/bzero.Tahiti_1573.4_1573.4 (VM).kernel (30492 bytes)

[s]tatus [p]ause [r]esume [b]ypass [q]uit =>
```

, but there are some reasons that make me need the classic CMD shell, like usage with CygWin (that should allow me to use GNU Screen, but this is another matter).

I think the problem comes from that `./kernels...` reference, that makes the command line program (`OCLHashCat`) try to search the directory in the running path, instead of searching for it in the origin path (the program`s path tree).

Could anyone please give me some idea to try?

EXTRA INFO: The program `OCLHashCat` has Linux and Windows versions, so it could be some compilation/programming problem or equivalent.

EXTRA INFO 2: This program has changed version 4-5 times in the last year, and I keep having this problem with it.

EXTRA INFO under requestion:

```
PS C:\Temporal> get-command oclHashcat64.exe | fl *

HelpUri         :
FileVersionInfo : File:             d:\Programas\HashCat\OCLHashCat\oclHashcat6
                  4.exe
                  InternalName:
                  OriginalFilename:
                  FileVersion:
                  FileDescription:
                  Product:
                  ProductVersion:
                  Debug:            False
                  Patched:          False
                  PreRelease:       False
                  PrivateBuild:     False
                  SpecialBuild:     False
                  Language:

Path            : d:\Programas\HashCat\OCLHashCat\oclHashcat64.exe
Extension       : .exe
Definition      : d:\Programas\HashCat\OCLHashCat\oclHashcat64.exe
Visibility      : Public
OutputType      : {System.String}
Name            : oclHashcat64.exe
CommandType     : Application
ModuleName      :
Module          :
Parameters      :
ParameterSets   :
```

So, the path in PowerShell seems correct.

EXTRA INFO about SSH: By SSHing into my computer (Windows 7 SP1 running Bitvise SSH Server) the behavior is exactly the same. It doesn't work for standard shell:

```
login as: Luis-
Luis-@Windu-'s password:
Microsoft Windows [Versión 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. Reservados todos los derechos.

C:\Users\Luis->cd \Temporal

C:\Temporal>oclhashcat64 Test.hccap -m 2500 -a 3 ?d?d?d?d?d?d?d?d
oclHashcat v1.31 starting...

WARN: ADL_Overdrive6_FanSpeed_Get(): -5

Device #1: Bonaire, 1024MB, 1050Mhz, 12MCU
Device #2: Tahiti, 3072MB, 900Mhz, 28MCU

Hashes: 1 hashes; 1 unique digests, 1 unique salts
Bitmaps: 8 bits, 256 entries, 0x000000ff mask, 1024 bytes
Applicable Optimizers:
* Zero-Byte
* Single-Hash
* Single-Salt
* Brute-Force
Watchdog: Temperature abort trigger set to 90c
Watchdog: Temperature retain trigger set to 80c
Device #1: Kernel ./kernels/4098/m02500.Bonaire_1573.4_1573.4 (VM).kernel not found
 in cache! Building may take a while...

ERROR: ./kernels/4098/m02500.VLIW1.llvmir: No such file or directory
```

and does for powershell:

```
login as: Luis-
Luis-@Windu-'s password:
Microsoft Windows [Versión 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. Reservados todos los derechos.

C:\Users\Luis->powershell
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. Reservados todos los derechos.

PS C:\Users\Luis-> cd \
PS C:\> cd .\Temporal
PS C:\Temporal> oclHashcat64.exe Test.hccap -m 2500 -a 3 ?d?d?d?d?d?d?d?d
oclHashcat v1.31 starting...

WARN: ADL_Overdrive6_FanSpeed_Get(): -5

Device #1: Bonaire, 1024MB, 1050Mhz, 12MCU
Device #2: Tahiti, 3072MB, 900Mhz, 28MCU

Hashes: 1 hashes; 1 unique digests, 1 unique salts
Bitmaps: 8 bits, 256 entries, 0x000000ff mask, 1024 bytes
Applicable Optimizers:
* Zero-Byte
* Single-Hash
* Single-Salt
* Brute-Force
Watchdog: Temperature abort trigger set to 90c
Watchdog: Temperature retain trigger set to 80c
Device #1: Kernel d:\Programas\HashCat\OCLHashCat/kernels/4098/m02500.Bonaire_1573.
4_1573.4 (VM).kernel (259320 bytes)
Device #1: Kernel d:\Programas\HashCat\OCLHashCat/kernels/4098/markov_le_v1.Bonaire
_1573.4_1573.4 (VM).kernel (92404 bytes)
Device #1: Kernel d:\Programas\HashCat\OCLHashCat/kernels/4098/bzero.Bonaire_1573.4
_1573.4 (VM).kernel (30496 bytes)
Device #2: Kernel d:\Programas\HashCat\OCLHashCat/kernels/4098/m02500.Tahiti_1573.4
_1573.4 (VM).kernel (259428 bytes)
Device #2: Kernel d:\Programas\HashCat\OCLHashCat/kernels/4098/markov_le_v1.Tahiti_
1573.4_1573.4 (VM).kernel (92388 bytes)
Device #2: Kernel d:\Programas\HashCat\OCLHashCat/kernels/4098/bzero.Tahiti_1573.4_
1573.4 (VM).kernel (30492 bytes)

[s]tatus [p]ause [r]esume [b]ypass [q]uit =>
```

EXTRA INFO upon requestion:

```
C:\Temporal>oclhashcat64 "c:\Temporal\Test.hccap" -m 2500 -a 3 ?d?d?d?d?d?d?d?d
oclHashcat v1.31 starting...

Device #1: Bonaire, 1024MB, 1050Mhz, 12MCU
Device #2: Tahiti, 3072MB, 900Mhz, 28MCU

Hashes: 1 hashes; 1 unique digests, 1 unique salts
Bitmaps: 8 bits, 256 entries, 0x000000ff mask, 1024 bytes
Applicable Optimizers:
* Zero-Byte
* Single-Hash
* Single-Salt
* Brute-Force
Watchdog: Temperature abort trigger set to 90c
Watchdog: Temperature retain trigger set to 80c
Device #1: Kernel ./kernels/4098/m02500.Bonaire_1573.4_1573.4 (VM).kernel not fo
und in cache! Building may take a while...

ERROR: ./kernels/4098/m02500.VLIW1.llvmir: No such file or directory
```

EXTRA INFO about running on CygWin:

```
Luis@Windu /cygdrive/c/Temporal
$ oclhashcat64 Test.hccap -m 2500 -a 3 ?d?d?d?d?d?d?d?d
oclHashcat v1.31 starting...

Device #1: Bonaire, 1024MB, 1050Mhz, 12MCU
Device #2: Tahiti, 3072MB, 900Mhz, 28MCU

Hashes: 1 hashes; 1 unique digests, 1 unique salts
Bitmaps: 8 bits, 256 entries, 0x000000ff mask, 1024 bytes
Applicable Optimizers:
* Zero-Byte
* Single-Hash
* Single-Salt
* Brute-Force
Watchdog: Temperature abort trigger set to 90c
Watchdog: Temperature retain trigger set to 80c
Device #1: Kernel D:\Programas\HashCat\OCLHashCat/kernels/4098/m02500.Bonaire_1573.4_1573.4 (VM).kernel (259320 bytes)
Device #1: Kernel D:\Programas\HashCat\OCLHashCat/kernels/4098/markov_le_v1.Bonaire_1573.4_1573.4 (VM).kernel (92404 bytes)
Device #1: Kernel D:\Programas\HashCat\OCLHashCat/kernels/4098/bzero.Bonaire_1573.4_1573.4 (VM).kernel (30496 bytes)
Device #2: Kernel D:\Programas\HashCat\OCLHashCat/kernels/4098/m02500.Tahiti_1573.4_1573.4 (VM).kernel (259428 bytes)
Device #2: Kernel D:\Programas\HashCat\OCLHashCat/kernels/4098/markov_le_v1.Tahiti_1573.4_1573.4 (VM).kernel (92388 bytes)
Device #2: Kernel D:\Programas\HashCat\OCLHashCat/kernels/4098/bzero.Tahiti_1573.4_1573.4 (VM).kernel (30492 bytes)

[s]tatus [p]ause [r]esume [b]ypass [q]uit =>
```

So we can say that the program **works OK under CygWin**. Due to it was possibly programmed initially for Linux?

Maybe I could use this at least as some sort of workaround.

Comment: Show how you call it in powershell for comparison

Comment: Done, @AndyArismendi. Not very different, I fear.

Comment: Well in Powershell I see it's using the full path on the device lines vs where cmd is attempting relative.

Comment: This is just how the cmd shell works. When an application/command is run, the current directory is set to the shell's current location. It is not set to the application's location. Actually, I'm surprised that it works in PowerShell.

Comment: @mikez, this behavior keeps the same since the last year, even when the programmer has published new versions several times. I have added it to my post.

Comment: @AndyArismendi, maybe we could modify the current directory environment variable to point to the program's path? It could be some sort of workaround.

Comment: Try running `get-command oclHashcat64.exe | fl *` in powershell. Is the Path the one you expect it to running from? Compare this with `where oclHashcat64.exe` in the cmd prompt.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez Ok one last guess, is there a file in `C:\Users\Luis` called Test.hccap? Is it possible you are reading that one, not the one in `C:\Temporal`?

Comment: No `Test.hccap` file on `c:\Users\Luis`, @mikez. It seems I will have to keep using PowerShell for running this program for now :-( . Thanks you all for your help.

Comment: When you started powershell, what was the directory path?

Comment: @VikasGupta, I can start Powershell from any path, even from `WinKey+R` (`Run Menu`). I have checked from `f:\Temp` and `OCLHashCat` works OK in any path I start PowerShell from.

Comment: I'm curious... What happens if you run it in cmd using the full path to the hccap file, for example: `cd c:\temporal & oclhashcat64.exe c:\Temporal\test.hccap ...` ?

Comment: Added that info, @Eris. And some new data: it works on CygWin!

Comment: Your assumption is correct, @eryksun : `d:\Programas\HashCat\OCLHashCat\oclHashcat64.exe Test.hccap -m 2500 -a 3 ?d?d?d?d?d?d?d?d` solves the problem. Or at least it is a bearable workaround that I can work with. Maybe we can replace some of these parameters in order to enhance the solution?

Comment: This method seems to me a good workaround, @eryksun. You should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

This program apparently find its home from the command-line instead of calling `GetModuleFileName`. Unlike cmd, PowerShell doesn't use the `lpApplicationName` parameter of [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Instead it modifies the command line to use the full path. For example, it replaces `"oclHashcat64.exe"` with `"d:\Programas\HashCat\OCLHashCat\oclHashcat64.exe"`. In cmd you'd have to actually type out the full path.

As a workaround you can use the console API to [add an input alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681935%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for cmd.exe. The old doskey program provides a command-line interface for this API. This way when you type `oclHashcat64` into the console, cmd.exe will instead read the full path that's set in the alias:

```
doskey /exename=cmd.exe oclHashcat64="D:\Programas\HashCat\OCLHashCat\oclHashcat64.exe" $*
```

You can save aliases (i.e. macros) to a file using `doskey /macros:all > aliases`. Then load them using `doskey /macrofile=aliases`. You can also add a command in `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun` to load your aliases when cmd.exe starts.

Another option is to create a Windows shortcut (i.e. a shell32 link file) in some directory that's on your `PATH`. Use the full path to the executable in the command line, and leave the start in directory empty (i.e. inherit the shell's working directory). Append `.LNK` to the `PATHEXT` environment variable to avoid having to type the .lnk extension. (I find link files to be more convenient than using a batch file as a glorified shortcut. Plus they don't install a Ctrl-C handler like batch files do, which is one less thing to annoy me.)